# getting calling child class name in lifecycle methods

Tags: android, oop, android-lifecycle

As the title says:
How can I get the class reference of child activity/fragment in the parent's lifecycle methods like onResume()?

Or: who called the onResume()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you created your fragment you have an option to name it(tagging it).  Afterwards you can gain a reference to it by doing the following:

```
 Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG");
```

i am assuming your creating the fragment something like this:

```
  Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.MainFrameLayout,fragmentA,"YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG")
    .addToBackStack("YOUR_SOURCE_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
```

and i would probably call that stuff in onResumeFragment but you can do it in onResume()

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution. How about activities?